# Is there anyone who can help me with my Swift Project? Ive got an Firebase error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

If i want to build my old Projekt in Xcode i've got th e following  errors:

> /Users/xxx/Desktop/development/xxx/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/Firebase.h:15:9: 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
> /Users/xxx/Desktop/development/xxx/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:17:8: Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'

The Internet said, that i need to:

1. Exit Xcode
2. Remove the Temp Data from Xcode
3. Remove Pods folder, Podfile.lock and project.xcworkspace
4. pod install
5. Run Xcode

But this tutorial doesnt work for me..
Is there anyone, who had a another solution?

- Setup: IOS 14
- Xcode 12.0 beta 2
- Swift 5

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got same problem after '$ pod update' then I did:

```
1. Shift + alt + k at Xcode (clean).
2. Closed Xcode.
3. $ pod deintegrate
4. Deleted .xcworkspace (pay attention to not delete wrong file !!!)
5. $ pod repo update
6. $ pod install
```

and it's go back.

Answer (score 0):

`shift + command + k`

have you tried to clean build?
because I have this issue very often when uses firebase.

and sometimes it fix itself by doing this steps repeatedly clean build -> exit xcode -> run xcode -> try different simulator -> clean ,

Comment: well if you using repository like git, try to re-clone your project, it may have some issue from your xcode

Comment: I doesnt use a repo from git, simply a folder on my Desktop :/